# Grails 3.0 error, nullpointer

Tags: grails

I was just trying to run Grails 3.0.1 in commandline via "grails" but it failed with the following stacktrace:

```
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3137)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.git.GitProfileRepository.getAllProfiles(GitProfileRepository.groovy:72)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.ListProfilesCommand.handle(ListProfilesCommand.groovy:43)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:173)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.getBaseUsage(GrailsCli.groovy:118)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:162)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:99)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null
```

I'm using this version of Java

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

Comment: is this a fresh project or have you done changes?  what profile have you used to create? are there changes to build.gradle?

Comment: hi, I havent created any project I was just trying to run grails out of the box. I think the errors after the nullpointer are proxy issues since Im at the moment at university. I just used my normal user-account, grails 2.5 is running without any problems

Comment: please make sure, that you have a proper separated environment for g2.5 and g3 - they are really different.  best to ensure this by tools like gvm.

Comment: I just deleted 2.5 because we have to work with 3.0. Additionaly I adjusted the systemenvironmentvariables - is there anymore todo?

Comment: it should boil down to `$GRAILS_HOME` and the `$PATH`.  yet consider using http://gvmtool.net/ for reproducible results and also easier updates.  did removing g2.5 help?

Comment: no removing did not help, same result. Ill try the tool you linked me!

Comment: it was just a guess.  i doubt that it will solve the problem.  but it makes future updates smoother.  are you able to access https://github.com/grails/grails-profile-repository ? i'd say your initial comment the is the root cause.

Comment: yeah I tried also running commandline as Administrator but doesnt help either. EDIT: After creating a sample project (create-app) the normal "grails" command worked without error. What kind of access do you mean? I can open it with my browser.

Comment: I am also running into this issue due to the proxy issue you mentioned. I tried the workaround mentioned below but I still got an exception. When I manually added the profiles in my .grails directory I was able to at least create the app, although I am still getting some profile update exceptions. Check out: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11967 and  https://github.com/grails/grails-profile-repository

Answer (score 12):

I have tried all the things mentioned in different threads, including setting GRAILS_OPTS. The issue seems to go away after running 
`grails create-app myApp` and create a sample app.

Not sure why, but seems like a connection problem with the Grails repo, which resolved after running the command.