# "Error occurred running Grails CLI: null" when running grails 3.0 command line

Tags: grails

I'm trying to run `grails list-profiles`, but receive the following error:

```
snowch@snowch-ws2:~/repos$ grails list-profiles --stacktrace
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.grails.cli.profile.git.GitProfileRepository.getAllProfiles(GitProfileRepository.groovy:72)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.ListProfilesCommand.handle(ListProfilesCommand.groovy:43)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:173)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:99)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null
```

My versions are:

```
snowch@snowch-ws2:~/repos$ grails --version
| Grails Version: 3.0.1
| Groovy Version: 2.4.3
| JVM Version: 1.7.0_75
```

This was on a fresh install of grails and gvm.

The command `grails create-app myapp` works without error.

This question is similar to [Grails 3.0 error, nullpointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534820/grails-3-0-error-nullpointer), however, that question does not state what command is being run.

Comment: I had this error when using openjdk-9 on Ubuntu 14. When reverting to openjdk-8 it fixed this for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching online, I found that I needed to set my GRAILS_OPTS environment variable as follows before running the command:

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="-XX:-UseSplitVerifier -Xverify:none"
```

Source of fix: https://grails.org/news/1292028

Comment: and did this search result also explain why?

Comment: I've added the original source of the fix to the answer.  One post is hinting at the problem being a jvm bug.

Comment: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option UseSplitVerifier -Xverify:none; support was removed in 8.0
|

Comment: "Source of fix" link above does not appear to be what it once was.

Comment: i am trying to resolve with Grails v2.4.0 and Java v8. its not working for me

Answer (score 2):

I have not figured out, what is the exact cause of the error, but it seems to occur if you try to run grails 3 in the system where grails 2 is also installed.

What I did to get the command run - I created the project in a new directory. The directory for my old grails app was:
*/home/me/projects/oldgrailsapp*

when I tried to execute the grails command in */home/me/projects* it failed, but when I tried this **in another directory** */home/me/projects_new*, it succeeded. So I guess that the problem was that old grails configuration was somehow interfering with the new one.

I also removed references to old grails and groovy versions from the PATH variable by editing *.bashrc* file in my home directory (I really do not know if it was needed).

Answer (score 2):

I had same experience when I was working on "[Building an Andoird Client](http://guides.grails.org/building-an-android-client-powered-by-a-grails-backend/guide/index.html)" guide, I got the following message whenever I try to create an app in the same folder where I've created the first app `grails-app` :
`| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null (Use --stacktrace to see the ful
l trace)`
So obviously, when you create a grails app in folder containing "grails-app" directory, grails will consider this folder as full grails application, hence cannot create-app in that directory.
I used:
Grails 3.1.15
Java 1.8.0.101
Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

**It worked for me now.**
this was my setting

GRAILS_HOME=C:\Users\murali.solayappan\apps\grails-3.1.11

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102

I received the same error while launching "grails" for the first time

```
**Error occurred running Grails CLI: connect timed out**
```

After reading GRAILS_HOME\bin\grails.bat i found that executing "grails" while in GRAILS_HOME dir makes some difference. So I did the same

Now i received error stating that GRAILS couldn't find a particular maven package from my mirror repository - printed my private nexus repository url. I know that's my private repo and not connected to internet.

so I changed the MY_HOME_DIR.m2\"settings.xml" with the one came by default in Maven.

After that executed "grails" while in %GRAILS_HOME% dir.

It worked like breeze !!!  I got grails prompt.

C:\Users\murali.solayappan\apps>grails

| Enter a command name to run. Use TAB for completion:

*grails>* exit

Answer (score 0):

Somethimes it happens when you have wrong version of grails installed for the project you want to run it on
try to run it somewhere else and see if you get the same error

Answer (score -1):

i had the same issue because i was using Grails 1.3.5 witj Java 8 which are incompatibles. I changed with Java 7 and it works fine.

Comment: Java 7 has not received any security update since more than three years. Using it is a huge security risk and should be avoided whenever possible!

Comment: Nica Haase, i think there is a lot of grails projects which use version under Grails 3 and which can have this issue... I give a solution to run an old project but yes it's better to update it with a more recent version of java and grails