# Getting error in GGTS for create a new project for Grails

Tags: grails, spring-tool-suite

When I am trying to create a new Grails project getting the following error:

Grails: 3.0.9
Jdk: 1.8

Command terminated with an exception: java.lang.Exception (see details for partial output)
Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\javaw.exe (11-Nov-2015 11:43:39 am)
---- System.out ----

---- System.err ----
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

------System.out:-----------

------System.err:-----------
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Please help me to get the solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are running the project (or create) as a Java project instead of Grails project, cause it is trying to execute de Main java class

Comment: Thanks for your response but still I could not find if this is a case. Please let me know how can i identify but I have set up each and every thing as per Grails.

Comment: Ensure that you have included the grails version into the project and GGTS. When you create a New > Grails project you have to set the grails distribution you are going to use. If it havent been set before, you  have to include it.

Comment: No, I have already included the grails version in my project but once I am clicking on finish to create a new project I am getting this error.

Comment: When I tried to run the below command on command prompt I got the following error:

Comment: C:\grails\grails-3.0.9\bin>grails
Usage:
         create-app [NAME] --profile=web
         create-plugin [NAME] --profile=web-plugin


| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null (Use --stacktrace to see the ful
l trace)

Comment: See this url for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758697/error-occurred-running-grails-cli-null-when-running-grails-3-0-command-line

Comment: I have again tried to set up the environmental variables but no recovery.:(

Comment: Have you used previous versions of grails in your machine ? What OS do u use?

Comment: This is the first time I am using Grails:

Comment: Below is the grails version | Grails Version: 3.0.9
| Groovy Version: 2.4.5
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_65

Comment: OS: windows 7 home premium

Comment: How can I check if there is another version of Grails exists, I need to check if my friened has never installed the same.

Comment: Check the .grails folder into your os user folder, you will find a folder for each version you have run before. If you have another you are free to delete them.

Comment: I have checked but there is no other version exists except which I am using i.e. Grails 3.0.9

Comment: just to know, why don't you try with the latest 2.x version (2.5.2 i guess). The 3.0.9 is very new, and many plugins does not support that version yet, and could have other bugs. Are you using the 3.x version for some reason?

Comment: Not for any specific reason I just got the latest version only from the grails.org, if its a version specific problem I can try the same with 2.X version also.