# Error occured while running Grails Project

Tags: grails

I am running Grails Project with below configuration On Ubuntu 14.04 machine  but getting below mentioned error.
Please refer the grails version below.

**grails –version**
Grails Version: 3.1.10
Groovy Version: 2.4.7
JVM Version: 1.8.0_101

Here is the  Error:
**grails run-app**

Error occurred running Grails CLI: null
                java.lang.NullPointerException
                    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeProfile(GrailsCli.groovy:511)
                    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeApplication(GrailsCli.groovy:310)
                    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:273)
                    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:163)
Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null

I have already checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758697/error-occurred-running-grails-cli-null-when-running-grails-3-0-command-line) but in vain.

Please help !!

Comment: Try `grails run-app --verbose` to obtain more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PS:- It may not help everyone but it works for me.

Solution:- I uninstalled grails & groovy from my machine . And re-install
Then it works fine.

I assumed that while installing Grails & groovy on my machine, I had few broken packages which were causing this issue.

Beginners cam refer this [link](http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners-setup-your-windows-development-environment) for setup etc.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned .gradle folder in Users\user and "build" in my project - this solved the problem