# Grails Set Up Environment Variables

Tags: grails, environment-variables

I have followed the documentation with regards to setting Grails up on Windows, but for some reason it is not working. Any help would be much appreciated

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you restart cmd after adding variable?

Comment: edit see above ^^ @MamyKryzysKryzysKryzys

Comment: I get an error when I try to launch it @MamyKryzysKryzysKryzys

Comment: use --stacktrace as is said and show output. moreover which version of grails are you using?

Comment: 3.0.11 is the version im using. See above I put the stack trace up. Thanks again @MamyKryzysKryzysKryzys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grails 3.0 error, nullpointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534820/grails-3-0-error-nullpointer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534820/grails-3-0-error-nullpointer):

shortly: just run once *grails create-app myApp*

Comment: I did just before I saw this thanks though it solved the problem :)