# Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null

Tags: grails

I'm completely new to Grails. I was trying to execute some command using grails but the error `error occurred running Grails CLI: null` keeps bothering me, the full stack trace is:

```
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeProfile(GrailsCli.groovy:511)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeApplication(GrailsCli.groovy:310)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:273)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:163)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null
```

I did some research and I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758697/error-occurred-running-grails-cli-null-when-running-grails-3-0-command-line) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534820/grails-3-0-error-nullpointer), tried all methods and neither of them working in my case. I cannot even run `grails create-app myApp`

The version I'm using are:

```
| Grails Version: 3.1.8
| Groovy Version: 2.4.6
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_71
```

Does anyone had same issue? Any thought will be appreciated, thank you!

I found that this error only occur when I execute command `grails` under my project directory, as long as I'm not in the project directory, `grails` is running fine. So weird...

Comment: are you behind a firewall, that would prevent access to github?

Comment: I'm using the svn actually...

Comment: As long as your are not in current project directory.... hmm mm maybe you have done something foobar to your project directory.  Try creating a new project directory move the projects into it after you have made the new project dir your new home and successfully built your new grails app in there. Alternatively create a new app outside dir move into dir cd  into app then try grails run-app it sounds like your project folder may already contain files that makes it into app or something weird. Try listing hidden files ls -artml under Linux